# Частичная расшифровка файла

Tags: c++, qt

Есть файлы, зашифрованные с помощью библиотеки Crypto++, алгоритм CBC.

```
const byte* key = ...;
const byte* iv = ...;
QByteArray dataChunck

CFB_Mode<AES>::Encryption encrypt(key, 32, iv);
encrypt.ProcessData((byte*)dataChunck.data(), (byte*)dataChunck.data(), dataChunck.size());
```

Расшифровка почти такая же:

```
CFB_Mode<AES>::Decryption encrypt(key, 32, iv);
encrypt.ProcessData((byte*)dataChunck.data(), (byte*)dataChunck.data(), dataChunck.size());
```

И все это работает, если декодировать файл с начала и до конца. Но вот появилась необходимость частичной расшифровки файла (для поддержки заголовка `Range` у HTTP сервера). 
Вариант в лоб - декодировать файл полностью и забирать оттуда только нужные байты. Но может есть способ, декодировать только нужные байты?

Если просто вместо `dataChunk` передавать нужный мне фрагмент, то получаю на выходе мусор, подозреваю что должно быть "правильное выравнивание" или еще соблюдать какой-то нюанс.

Comment: В режиме CBC содержимое каждого последующего шифроблока зависит от предыдущего. Так что вам в любом случае придётся расшифровывать всю цепочку блоков, пусть даже если её начало и не требуется.

Comment: Если знать границы "зависимого" шифрования (размер блока), то можно часть "блоков" не расшифровывать. Возможно размер блока кратен 4096. Попробуте пропустить 4К и расшифровать блок 4К. Если получится - то можно расшифровывать блоки кратно 4К.

Comment: в коде CFB, а не CBC, но это погоды не делает... всё равно расшифровывать можно только с начала...

Comment: Думается, вам надо посмотреть в сторону потокового шифрования https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Stream_Cipher или хранить файлы незашифрованные, а шифровать непосредственно выдаваемый блок информации

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, результатом я доволен.
Действительно ошибся немного в описание, шифрование `CFB`, а не `CBC`.

Методом проб и ошибок, стало ясно, что частичная расшифровка дает нормальный результат, если указывать диапазон кратный 16 байтам (это размер вектора инициализации), но при этом, первые 16 байт испорченные. Потому я получаю позицию, откуда нужно получить данные, смещаю её вниз до ближайшего числа, кратного 16 и затем еще отнимаю 16 байт (которые будут испорченные). Данные отправляем на декодирование, и от полученного результата отрезаем начало на лишнее количество байт.

```
qint64 roundToPrev16(qint64 _currentPos)
{
    const int magicDiv = 16;

    qint64 x = _currentPos / magicDiv;

    qint64 res = x * magicDiv;
    res -= 16;
    return res;
}
```

Итого оверхэд не слишком большой (не более 32 байт). А так как данный алгоритм используется при Range запросах на HTTP сервер, который актуален обычно для мультимедийных файлов и составляет 1-20 мбайт, то расшифровка лишних 32 байт не сказывается на производительности.

Comment: "Методом проб и ошибок" — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Feedback_(CFB) а можно было просто описание прочитать =)

Comment: И, кстати, 16 байт это 128 бит — размер блока AES. https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#Block_Size